# How to dynamically create specific number of rows in a report table

Tags: devexpress, xtrareport

Problem is a little weird. My datasource object has some boolean properties and I want to create a table with the number of rows based on values of these properties. For example if values are True, True, False I need 2 rows. How to accomplish such task?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a XRTable. There you can dynamicly add rows easily. Just create XRTableRow object. Fill it with some XRTableCell objects and then say:

```
XRTable.InsertRowBelow();
```

So you can run over your objects and foreach boolean = true, you create one row and insert it into your table.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [XtraReportBase.FilterString Property](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/DevExpressXtraReportsUIXtraReportBase_FilterStringtopic) to filter rows from your data source.